# Can I use 12 awg ground copper for 14 awg electrical box wirings?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My electrical box has 14 awg wires and I have a 12 awg copper ground wire lying around.  Can I use the 12 awg copper or do I need to get a 14 gauge?

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine. If it's just pigtails in the box it won't even affect your fill, IIRC. If you are running 12Ga ground wire (not just in-box pigtails) you do have to allow for it in box volume calculations, but it would rarely cause a problem since the equipment grounding conductor is only counted once for box fill.

Comment: I plan on putting three ground wires from the 3 switches into a twist nut and then pigtailing the extra copper ground to the metal electric box.

Answer (score 1):

No problem.  Just make sure all the terminals are rated for 12 AWG, and any connectors are sized to accept the number and size of wires being connected.